# MapStruct: map one object to List of another one

Tags: java, mapping, mapstruct

I have a request, that contains two different arrays

```json
{
   "my_object": {
      "foo" : [
         ...
      ],
      "bar" : [
         ...
      ],
      // other fields
   }
}
```

I want map `foo` and `bar` to List of `baz` object, so I wrote something like:

```java
// MyObjectMapper.java

    @Named("fromMyObject")
    default List<Baz> fromMyObject(MyObject myObject) {
        List<Baz> result = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Foo foo: myObject.getFoo()) {
            result.add(map(foo));
        }

        for (Bar bar: myObject.getBar()) {
            result.add(map(bar));             
        }

        return result;
    }
```

And use it as: `@Mapping(target = "fooAndBar", source =".", qualifiedByName = "fromMyObject")`

But I get the following error:

> Qualifier error. No method found annotated with @Named#value: [
> fromMyObject]. See https://mapstruct.org/faq/#qualifier for more info.

What is wrong?